# How to select random rows where the sum of a column equals to X - MySQL

Tags: mysql, random, rows

How i can select random rows of a table when the sum of a column equals to a value ? (MySQL)

```
    Value : 3

    Name               Price
    ------------------------
    A                  1
    B                  2
    C                  1
    D                  3
    E                  2
```

I wan to get all possibilities (A + B, D, E + C...).

I have tried to do this :

```
SELECT * FROM table HAVING SUM(column) = 3 ORDER BY RAND();
```

Thank's
Thibeault

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any attempts you've made at solving this issue on your own. If you haven't yet attempted to solve your own question, then you've likely posted your question here a bit preemptively.

Comment: Use a self-join to get all the pairs, then `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to pick one of them at random.

Comment: Can you give me a example please ? @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table with itself to get pairs of rows.

```
SELECT t1.name as name1, t1.price as price1, t2.name AS name2, t2.price AS price2
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.price + t2.price = 3
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Last question, it's possible to define more than 2 possibilities ? (the maximum of possibilites, not add t3, t4 etc.)

Comment: There may be a way, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: This deals with x + y, but not x + y + z. Maybe SUM() can help with that, but this isn't really what SQL is good at